# Getting key inside reduceByKey() api spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way i can get the name of the key in pyspark inside the reduceByKey() function so that i can get what key is common between the two values passed into the reduceByKey() function ?

For example:

```
inside reduceByKey(combineValues) where

def combineValues(a,b): 
//can i get the key value common to both a and b here ?? 
return a+b;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aggregate` function on RDD, however you lose the HashPartitioner benefit, so I would suggest storing the key in your values if it's important.

Comment: So there is no way to get that key name inside API like aggregateByKey or reduceByKey? This is my first time using spark so excuse me if i ask trivial questions. Are you saying reduceByKey() does hash partitioning by itself ? I thought you were supposed to do that explicitly yourself for reduceByKey().

Comment: Yes, `reduceByKey` will put a hash partitioner on your set, that's actually why you do NOT have access to the key. It guarantees that the key is left in place.